# Irreducible Polynomial examples in Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

In Chapter 17 of Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*, 8th Edition, irreducible polynomials are defined as: in an integral domain $D$, whenever $f(x)$ from $D[x]$ is expressed as a product $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, with $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ from $D[x]$, then $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ is a unit in $D[x]$. Their first example is $f(x)=2x^2+4$, which is irreducible over $Q$ (presumably because $2$ is a unit, since it's inverse $\frac{1}{2}$ is also in $Q[x]$?), but is reducible over $Z$, because neither $2$ nor $x^2+2$ is a unit in $Z[x]$.

This makes sense to me, but the very next example says that the same $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\textbf{R}$ but reducible over $\textbf{C}$, and I don't understand. By the same definition, I think that either (or both) $2$ or $x^2+2$ *is* a unit in $\textbf{R}[x]$, but that *neither* is a unit in $\textbf{C}[x]$, but I don't understand why $2^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}$ isn't part of $\textbf{C}[x]$. To be clear, I *do* understand that $f(x)=2x^2+4$ must be reducible over $\textbf{C}$ by later theorems (because it has a zero in the field $\textbf{C}$), I just don't understand the implication that neither $2$ nor $x^2+2$ is a unit in $\textbf{C}[x]$.

Comment: $x^2+2$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.  And he never claims that "neither $2$ nor $x^2+2$ is a unit in $\mathbb{C}[x]$."  You're misunderstanding the definition.

Comment: The fact that, yes, $2$ is a unit in $\mathbb{C}$ has nearly nothing to say about its reducibility.  To be reducible means that *there exists one* factorization without unit terms, not that ALL factorizations must never have any unit terms.

Comment: @Randall, thank you, yes I'm definitely misunderstanding something. The definition says that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $D[x]$, if *whenever* $f(x)$ is expressed as a product $g(x)h(x)$, then $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ is a unit in $D[x]$ (emphasis added). Is "whenever" just a bad word choice in the text? In their first example, they explicitly state that $f(x)$ is reducible over $Z$ because "neither $2$ nor $x^2+2$ is a unit in $Z[x]$", seeming to imply that the unit test of any $g(x)h(x)$ is enough.

Comment: No, "whenever" is fine, because it means "in every case."  And they are still correct with the last example, because they have exhibited ONE factorization where no term is a unit, which means it IS NOT irreducible.

Comment: OK, so if I'm understanding you correctly, this test only works in one direction. When their first example says that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $Q$ but reducible over $Z$ for the reason I already typed, they are apparently *not* saying that it's irreducible over $Q$ because of the fact that $2$ is a unit? To use the definition as a proof that $f(x)$ is irreducible, I would have to find every possible $g(x)h(x)$ and show that those $g(x)$'s and $h(x)$'s are *never* units in $Q[x]$?

Comment: No, to show that $f$ is irreducible you must find every possible factorization $gh$ and show that *at least one* of $g$ or $h$ is a unit in every one of these factorizations.